# tableau calculated field with condition giving error

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to sum how much records my ML model was TP - table_classification = 1 and labeled=1

```
sum([model_classification]=1 AND [model_labeled]=1)
```

getting the below error:

```
sum is being called with boolean, did you mean float?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sum(INT([model_classification]=1 AND [model_labeled]=1))
```

`INT` will convert boolean to Integer/numeric and thereaftyou can perform arithmetic calculation on that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28219661)

Comment: @Amit Verma, this is not a comment, but an answer to the post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, looks much meaningful now!